I want to extract only the graph parts from this image in python how do i go about it?
I want to extract the two graphs on the right hand side together nor seperately both can be extracted as one (https://i.sstatic.net/RqwkB.jpg)
Im not sure what to try i am very new to this. I am using python and i hae extracted the text from the image and saved it in a csv
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image_path = r'C:\Prarthana\PROJECTS\GitHub\MajorProject\Images\1.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Apply Canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150)

# Find contours in the edge-detected image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Filter contours based on area to find the largest contour (assuming the graph is the largest area)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:1]

# Create a mask to extract the graph region
mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)

# Apply the mask to the original image to extract the graph
graph = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

# Save the extracted graph image
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Prarthana\PROJECTS\GitHub\MajorProject\Images\output\extracted_graph.jpg', graph)


You did not show us your attempt at solving this problem, also, if this is real data -> you must not upload other people's test results to a website!

@TinoD An attempt at solving a problem is not required, only encouraged.

@TylerH at some point questions start to read like a request to solve tasks and not to help someone in problems they are having with their task. This in my opinion was definitely the first one. And given that all OP did after my comment was go to chatGPT and generate garbage that OP then copy/pasted here as "their attempt" is even more insulting. KRG did a great job answering the question and OP asked for more and then ghosted. Finally the scan is most definitely something that should not be shared in public!

Your issues with OP's actions are irrelevant to the fact that attempts are not required when posting a question on Stack Overflow.

I preprocessed the image and used  LineSegmentDetector to find the line segments. Later used some logical constraints to find the graph. Try below code, I have added comments for the explanation of each steps. Hope this help.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

#Def to Calculate distance between 2 points
def distanceCalculate(p1, p2):
    """p1 and p2 in format (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) tuples"""
    dis = ((p2[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p2[1] - p1[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
    return dis


# Load the image
image_path = 'graphs.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Threshold the image to obtain only the black parts
ret, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#Invert the image
thresholded_image = 255 - thresholded_image

#Do an erosion operation using cross structure kernal to remove parts the are not horizontal or vertical
kernel =  cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(5,5))
thresholded_image = cv2.erode(thresholded_image,kernel,iterations = 1)

#Use LineSegmentDetector in CV2 to dinf the line segments in the image
lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)
dlines = lsd.detect(thresholded_image)

#Get the line segments in the image
#Find the distance and angle of the found line segments.
#I select the line segment if the distance is > 25 and angle between 0 to 5 for horizontal aned 85 to 90 for vertical lines
line_image = np.zeros_like(thresholded_image)
for dline in dlines[0]:
    x0 = int(round(dline[0][0]))
    y0 = int(round(dline[0][1]))
    x1 = int(round(dline[0][2]))
    y1 = int(round(dline[0][3]))
    dis = distanceCalculate([x0, y0],[x1,y1])
    angle_between = math.degrees(math.atan2(abs(y1-y0), abs(x1-x0)))
    if dis>25 and (0<=angle_between<5 or 85<angle_between<=90):
        cv2.line(line_image, (x0, y0), (x1,y1), 255, 5, cv2.LINE_AA)

#Dilate the the line image to fill gaps in between
kernel =  cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(5,5))
line_image = cv2.dilate(line_image,kernel,iterations = 1)

#Find fontour and the associated bounding box
#The area of graph bounding boxes will be large compared to other small line contours, this is used to find the graphs
graph_mask = np.zeros_like(thresholded_image)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(line_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
selected_bounding_rect = []
for ctr in contours:
    bounding_rect = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    bounding_rect_area = bounding_rect[2] * bounding_rect[3]
    if bounding_rect_area>15000:# This can be adjusted according to your need.
        contour_image = cv2.rectangle(graph_mask,bounding_rect,255,-1)

#Get the graph from original image from the mask
selected_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=graph_mask)
# Save the extracted graph image
cv2.imwrite('graph_result.jpg', selected_image)

Output image :


This is the required output right? If you need to join the graphs,  you can join the 2 rectangles in graph mask and extract from image.
